# Drawing a Triangle Shape

Tags: android

I am trying to draw a Triangle in Android, but I don't what the code for it. I am drawing with a canvas. I want to draw the Triangle Shape.

For example I already know for Rectangle:

```
Rect rectangle = new Rect();
```

But I don't know whats the code for the Triangle. Please provide the code in which I could make the Triangle :)

I thank everyone who will help me.

Comment: Are you asking about drawing on `Canvas`?

Comment: If you mean actually drawing, you'll have to do it with `drawLine*()` or `drawPath()`.

Comment: Yes I am drawing on canvas

Comment: Use a **path** object

Comment: I actually don't mean drawing by the word. But for example when I make

Rect rectangle = new Rect(); It will give me the shape of a rectangle

Comment: Guys can you please answer it instead of commenting so I would see the best answer and vote for it? 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Path` object.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(x1, y1);
path.lineTo(x2, y2);
path.lineTo(x3, y3);
path.close(); // or path.lineTo(x1, y1);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Where `Xn` and `Yn` are the triangle vertices.

Alternatively, you can use a single call:

```
float []points = {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3};
canvas.drawVertices(Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES, points.length, points, 0, null, 0, null, 0, null, 0, 0, paint);
```

Note that the `drawVertices` might not be rendered right if hardware acceleration is enabled (check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported)).